# Get Data from Entity Framework Core (.NET 8) on an API gives the error: Only the invariant culture is supported in globalization-invariant

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-8.0

I created an example to illustrate this error: I added an ASP.NET Core 8 Web API. Then, I created class A with one property:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace api
{
    [Table("A")]
    public class TableExample
    {
        [Column("Example")]
        public int ColumnExample { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I have a database with A table with this column `Example`. I created this `DbContext` class:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace api
{
    public class Context : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<TableExample> TableExamples { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Data Source=datasource;Initial Catalog=database;Trusted_Connection=true;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;TrustServerCertificate=True");
            base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
    }
}
```

In my controller I just need to get the data, like this:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace api.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class WeatherForecastController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet(Name = "GetWeatherForecast")]
        public IActionResult Get()
        {
            Context context = new Context();
            var test = context.TableExamples.ToList();

            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this example, I get this error:

[image]

I created a console app to test, with the same classes as shown above. In my `Program.cs`, I have this code:

```
using api;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Context context = new Context();
            var teste = context.TableExamples.ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

In this case, the code works perfectly.

How to correct this error in the API? I searched for this and talks about configure `Globalization.Invariant` to false, but I don't configure nothing in my `launchSettings.json` (https://aka.ms/GlobalizationInvariantMode)

Example of my `LaunchSettings.json`:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:35135",
      "sslPort": 44348
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "http": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5024",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "https": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7164;http://localhost:5024",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Modify the setting in your .csproj

Comment: Can you please share full [mre]? For example at github?

Comment: In your launchSettings.json file, you can add this environment variable to your environment variables section. For example:`"environmentVariables": {
"ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
"DOTNET_SYSTEM_GLOBALIZATION_INVARIANT": "false"
}` 
This should be added under all profiles. you can manually set the culture when the program starts, such as in 'Program.cs or Startup.cs':`using System.Globalization;
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");`Replace 'en-US' for any locale you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

open your project's csproj file and set

```
<InvariantGlobalization>true</InvariantGlobalization>
```

**to**

```
<InvariantGlobalization>false</InvariantGlobalization>
```